# MYSQL - Getting Values From Two Tables on Match

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a value from two tables on match.

**Booking Table:**

```
 id, member_id, salon_id, service_id, appointment_date, booking_date
  1,         5,        2,          1,       2015-08-29,   2015-08-29
  2,         5,        2,          2,       2015-08-29,   2015-08-29
  3,         5,        3,          3,       2015-08-29,   2015-08-29
  4,         5,        3,          4,       2015-08-29,   2015-08-29
```

**Services Table:**

```
 service_id, salon_id, service_name, price
          1,        2, Make-Up     , 25
          2,        2, Hair Styling, 10
          3,        3, Waxing      , 15
          4,        3, Threading   , 20
```

**Current Query:**

```
SELECT b.salon_id 
     , s.service_id
     , s.price
     , b.booking_date 
  FROM bookings b
  JOIN services s
    ON b.salon_id = s.salon_id 
   AND b.salon_id = 2 
   AND b.booking_date = '2015-08-29';
```

**Current Result:**

```
  salon_id, service_id, price, booking_date
         2,          1,    25,   2015-08-29
         2,          1,    25,   2015-08-29
         2,          2,    10,   2015-08-29
         2,          2,    10,   2015-08-29
```

**Expected Result:**

```
 salon_id, service_id, price, booking_date
        2,          1,    25, 2015-08-29
        2,          2,    10, 2015-08-29
```

What i am trying to do is. I want all the specific salon booking for specific date. After that i will sum price to get total sales of salon for specific date.

Any help please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you also need a condition on the services id in the join:

```
SELECT b.salon_id, s.service_id, s.price, b.booking_date
FROM bookings b INNER JOIN
     services s
     ON b.salon_id = s.salon_id AND
        b.service_id = s.service_id
WHERE b.salon_id = 2 AND
      b.booking_date = '2015-08-29';
```

Also notice how table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: This one is also works perfectly. Now which one is the efficient one? :S

Comment: Probably this one... more thought has been applied :)

Comment: @Yas . . . More important than efficiency, this uses what seems to be the correct conditions for the `join`.  From a performance perspective, a single `join` is generally going to have better performance than a `join` followed by `distinct`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the good explanation :). I mark it correct answer.

Comment: @mhawke Thanks for your help :) if you give my question vote up so i can give you vote up. At the moment i don't have permission to give vote up until i get 15 reputation.

Answer (score 2):

Try `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT bookings.salon_id, services.service_id, services.price,
bookings.booking_date FROM bookings INNER JOIN services ON
bookings.salon_id=services.salon_id AND bookings.salon_id = 2 AND
bookings.booking_date = '2015-08-29';
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT bookings.salon_id, services.service_id, services.price,bookings.booking_date 
FROM bookings 
LEFT JOIN services ON bookings.salon_id=services.salon_id AND bookings.service_id = services.service_id;
```

This query will display data from booking that exist in service.

bookings.salon_id=services.salon_id AND **bookings.salon_id = 2 AND
bookings.booking_date = '2015-08-29'**;

make your query not dynamic. How if you want to get salon_id 1 or 2 or 3 or all of them?